# How to use select statement in join condition in Impala sql

Tags: sql, oracle, join, impala

I am learning Impala sql and need to convert a sql query into impala equivalent which is something like this:

```
select distinct t1.c1, t1.c2 
  from table1 t1
       join table2 t2 
       on t2.c1=t1.c1 and (t2.c2 is null 
                           or t2.c2 in (select c1 from table3 
                                                 where 'some conditions')
                          )
```

When I am executing this query in impala I am getting error as "**Could not resolve table reference table3**". Although this **table3** is present in the database which I am using.

Can anyone please guide what is happening and why am I getting this table not found error.

Also please suggest how to implement this sql code into Impala equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

It does not support queries in ON join condition, rewrite query like this:

```
select distinct t1.c1, t1.c2 
  from table1 t1
       join table2 t2 on t2.c1=t1.c1
       left join (--prevent unintended duplication by join if c1 is not unique
                  select distinct c1 from 
                  table3 where 'some conditions') t3 on t2.c2=c3.c1  
 where t2.c2 is null --not joined with c3 because of null
    or t3.c1 is not null --or joined with c3
```

Comment: Should it be t3 or C3? Like c3.c1 or t3.c1?

Comment: @Sifu Yes, it should be t3.c1

Comment: Hi @leftjoin could you please take a look at this? Need your help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71378089/impala-conversion-of-oracle-query-competitive-hackathon